# How to edit scripts in Vuforia so that i can write functions with touchcount?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

Why cant I edit scripts in Vuforia.It is inaccesible.I want to write zooin function when touch with two fingers.I tried not working.When I touch on the screen it add the model I want to place.Whether i touch with one or two fingers it adds the model.So how to use single touch to place the model and double touch for zoom options.I turned off Duplicate stage.I am using the latest version of unity2018.1 and Vuforia 7.1.35

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create objects with ground plane detection only once with Vuforia & Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48635957/create-objects-with-ground-plane-detection-only-once-with-vuforia-unity)

Comment: Have you tried the latest version of Vuforia 7.1.35 and Unity 2018.1.The DeploymentStageOnce script,they have taken away from the tutorial.I dont have a clue about how to edit the scripts and the place the object with interactive touch.

Comment: You are right, they have removed it with Unity 2018