# i trying to Vuforia in my unity project but the script is not working

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

my Errors : 
1.Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'Anchor' does not contain a definition for 'transform' and no accessible extension method 'transform' accepting a first argument of type 'Anchor' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  Assembly-CSharp C:\Users\$$$\Documents\car\Assets\DeployStageOnce.cs    45  Active

2.Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'Vuforia.Anchor' to 'UnityEngine.GameObject' Assembly-CSharp C:\Users\$$$\Documents\car\Assets\DeployStageOnce.cs    55  Active

here`s my code:

```
    using System;
    using UnityEngine;
    using Vuforia;


    public class DeployStageOnce : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public GameObject AnchorStage;
        private PositionalDeviceTracker _deviceTracker;
        private GameObject _previousAnchor;

        public void Start()
        {
            if (AnchorStage == null)
            {
                Debug.Log("AnchorStage must be specified");
                return;
            }
            AnchorStage.SetActive(false);
        }

        public void Awake()
        {
            VuforiaARController.Instance.RegisterVuforiaStartedCallback(onVuforiaStarted);
        }
        public void OnDestroy()
        {
            VuforiaARController.Instance.UnregisterVuforiaStartedCallback(onVuforiaStarted);
        }
        private void onVuforiaStarted()
        {
            _deviceTracker = TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker<PositionalDeviceTracker>();
        }
        public void OnInteractiveHitTest(HitTestResult result)
        {
            if (result == null || AnchorStage == null)
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("Hit test is invalid or AnchorStage not set");
                return;
            }
            var anchor = _deviceTracker.CreatePlaneAnchor(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), result);

            if (anchor !=null)
            {
                AnchorStage.transform.parent = anchor.transform;
                AnchorStage.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
                AnchorStage.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.identity;
                AnchorStage.SetActive(true);
            }
            if (_previousAnchor != null)
            {
                Destroy(_previousAnchor);
            }

            _previousAnchor = anchor;
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/ground-plane/deploy-stage-once-script-now-broken most probably related -> That script seems to be deprecated

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [Create objects with ground plane detection only once with Vuforia & Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48635957/create-objects-with-ground-plane-detection-only-once-with-vuforia-unity/50677810)